# Calendar control showing long DayLength suddenly

Tags: vb6, calendar-control

I have a Calendar control on a VB6 form which on one machine is suddenly showing long day names instead of the single initials of the days like it is designed to.

```
eg. Monday instead of M
```

At design time this is set with the `DayLength` property which I have set to `Short`, but for some reason on one machine it is showing as though it is set to `Long`.

What is the cause of this?  Is there a registry setting or something else that would be doing this?

Comment: When you say "Calendar control" do you mean `DateTimePicker` or `MonthCalendar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unregister then register the calendar control.

This may be achieved by repairing or reinstalling the product.

Comment: Was that a solution to your own question or a note/comment?

Comment: @Deanna: should be obvious that it is an answer to my question.